# How to get past 6 months year and month based on the entered year and month(not present month) in bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, date, conditional-statements

Here is some of the code, I tried. I need to get past 6 months data (year & Month) based on the entered year and month.

Input and Output format:-

```
*/example program:
  please enter year:2019
  please enter month:05

output:
201904
201903
201902
201901
201812
201811/*
```

My Script:

```
if [ -z $1 ]
then
   echo Please enter year.
   exit
fi ,

if [ -z $2 ]
then
   echo Please enter month
   exit
fi ,
x=0
while [ "$x" -le 12 ]
do
year= date +'%Y%m' -d "$x month ago"
echo $year
((x++))
```

Comment: script:
if [ -z $1 ]
then
   echo Please enter year.
   exit
fi

if [ -z $2 ]
then
   echo Please enter month
   exit
fi
x=0
while [ "$x" -le 12 ]
do
year= date +'%Y%m' -d "$x month ago"
echo $year
((x++))

Comment: What is `,` doing after `fi`?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
date --date="$1-$2-01 -6 month" +%B
```

Demo:

```
date --date="2019-05-01 -6 month" +'6 month from date was %B!'
6 month from date was November!
```